# Login system for DAPP without metamask

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, dapps, myetherwallet

I'm building Dapp on Ethereum. Imagine I have companies to register in my dapp, I will provide them with their own smart contract and public and private key pair, which they will use to just unlock their account and perform some kind of changes in their smart contract.

So how should this account unlock happen? I just want to make it simple. Maybe I will provide them with ethereum account and just use this account's public and private key?

I Don't want to use Metamask, but I want to make Login system like MyEtherWallet without any chrome extention. What's the best way of doing so?

should I use centralized Database? because I think Dapp won't be decentralized anymore.

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean "login system like MyEtherWallet"? There's no login system on MEW, it just runs in your browser...

Comment: Build a user/login on your website and when the user becomes active, update some variable in your contract, that would indicate user is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing purpose we may use metamask/myetherwallet. But for production system in Dapp we have to manage account and its activites like sign the transaction. Here are common steps to make your Dapp functions well.

1. Account management : This is fundamental part to interact with contract funcitons. Here is [web3.eth.accounts](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html) module. this explans The web3.eth.accounts contains functions to generate Ethereum accounts and sign transactions and data. you can do almost all things that you do from metamask.
2. network RPC End point : Above accounts must be reside from the same network where and which you have enabled the RPC port. From web3 we use endpoint like

> var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

3. Dapp Hosting : Ultimately your blockchain is distributed and decentralized but your dapp no need to be distributed and decentralized. You can host any where you can like AWS, Google Cloud. Only you need is private/public key to interact with blockchain. It means that you have to take care of your account and signing mechanism that means keep your private key seperate and safe.

Whether you implement your dapp using web3 or native go language or any . The concept is the same.

Comment: Listen, I don't want to have my Node running, I am building just demo. This demo version should include also mobile (ionic) application, do you have any idea how is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

I've recently came across this project claiming to be alternative to MetaMask: https://fortmatic.com/

I just got into the alpha and started playing around with it, and so far looks promising, pretty good docs and integrates well with web3